# In Java 8, MyServicePort.java class is missing when generating java classes by using wsimport

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, java-8, wsimport

In Java8, Generated web service java classes by using

```
wsimport -keep http://sasikumar:8080/SimpleWebServiceServer/AdditionService?wsdl
```

I can't MyServicePort.java(AdditionPort.java) class from the generated files list

[image]

so anyone give me some idea about writing client stub without MyServicePort.java(AdditionPort.java) class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer goes a bit late. I had same issue while using maven plugin `jaxws-maven-plugin`. I was about to generate client code for some Microsoft service, everything went fine but Port and Service classes where missing. In debug enabled I saw the root cause, there was message:

```
[WARNING] Ignoring SOAP port "WSHttpBinding_IMyService": it uses non-standard SOAP 1.2 binding.
You must specify the "-extension" option to use this binding.
  line 1 of https://my.address.to.wsdl

[WARNING] Service "MyService" does not contain any usable ports. try running wsimport with -extension switch.
  line 1 of https://my.address.to.wsdl
```

Adding "-extension" resolved problem.